# Programa para simular o Paradoxo do aniversário

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemática

Em teoria das probabilidades, o paradoxo do aniversário afirma que dado um grupo de 23 (ou mais) pessoas escolhidas aleatoriamente, a chance de que duas pessoas terão a mesma data de aniversário é de mais de 50%. Para 57 ou mais pessoas, a probabilidade é maior do que 99%, entretanto, ela não pode ser exatamente 100% exceto que se tenha pelo menos 367 pessoas.

Escreva um programa que recebe um número n de pessoas e um número x de repetições e sorteia listas com datas de aniversário, e verifica se existe alguma data coincidente. Para cada loop deve-se re-sortear as listas, e para cada lista onde há casos coincidentes deve-se acrescentar 1 ao número de casos favoráveis. Depois de rodados os x loops de a porcentegem de vezes em que houve aniversários coincidentes.

Detalhe: Use compressão de listas para gerar as datas de aniversário

Tentativa de solução:

```
import random

datas =[x for x in range(1,366)]
#print(datas)


n = int(input("Digite o número de pessoas: "))
x = int(input("Digite o número de repetições: "))
datas_sorteadas = []
favoraveis = 0
for i in range(x):
    for i in range(n):
        datas_sorteadas.append(random.choice(datas))
        print(datas_sorteadas)

    for data in datas_sorteadas:
        if datas_sorteadas.count(data)>=2:
            favoraveis +=1
    datas_sorteadas = []
    datas_sorteadas.append(random.choice(datas))
    print(datas_sorteadas)

print("Casos Favoráveis: ", favoraveis)

print("n*x",n*x)
print("Percentual: ", (favoraveis/(n*x)))
#print(datas_sorteadas)
```

O programa está rodando sem erros mas desconfio que não está correto. Os resultados não condizem com a teoria. Alguma ideia de como corrigir?

Comment: Escreva uma bateria de testes unitários que reflitam o comportamento esperado, aí fica fácil de identificar quais casos não estão corretos.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pela descrição do problema, creio estás a fazer algumas coisas escusadas, é mais simples do que parece.

[O que é o paradoxo/problema do aniversário?](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxo_do_anivers%C3%A1rio)

[Video explicativo PT](https://pt.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/prob-comb/prob-combinatorics-precalc/v/birthday-probability-problem)

Para simular isto podemos fazer assim:

1. Receber como input o número de pessoas (`num_p`) e número de testes/repetições (`num_loops`) a fazer;
2. Em cada teste geramos uma lista com `num_p` (número de pessoas) inteiros aleatórios, cada um poderá ter um valor entre 1 e 365 para simular o dia de aniversário de cada pessoa. Ex: em um teste com 6 pessoas poderemos obter `[4, 144, 233, 98, 144, 43]`;
3. Verificar se na lista gerada existe algum valor que ocorra mais do que uma vez nessa mesma lista, neste caso faço uso de [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) e [`count()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/list_count.htm). Ex: `[4, 144, 233, 98, 144, 43]` (aniversários de 6 pessoas), neste caso 144 repete-se, ou seja, duas pessoas têm o mesmo dia de aniversário;
4. Caso o ponto acima (3) se verifique é porque temos pelo menos 1 valor que se repete, aí incrementamos a nossa variável `favoraveis`, e no final dos testes calcular a percentagem de `favoraveis` em `num_loops` (número de testes).

Código:

```
import random

num_p = int(input("Digite o número de pessoas: "))
num_loops = int(input("Digite o número de repetições: ")) # num de testes
favoraveis = 0
for _ in range(num_loops):
    ani_dates = [random.randint(1, 366) for _ in range(num_p)] # sortear nova lista de datas (dias) de aniversario
    if(any(ani_dates.count(i) > 1 for i in ani_dates)): # verificar se existe a mesma data (valor) mais do que uma vez na lista
        favoraveis += 1

probs_perc = (favoraveis/num_loops)*100
print('Em {} pessoas e {} testes deram-se {} vezes em que pelo menos duas pessoas fazem anos no mesmo dia, percentagem: {}%'.format(num_p, num_loops, favoraveis, probs_perc))
# Em 23 pessoas e 1000 testes deram-se 504 vezes em que pelo menos duas pessoas fazem anos no mesmo dia, percentagem: 50.4%
# Em 57 pessoas e 1000 testes deram-se 993 vezes em que pelo menos duas pessoas fazem anos no mesmo dia, percentagem: 99.3%
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/IrritatingImperturbableTheories)

#### Edição

Depois de rever esta resposta e realizar alguns testes notei que conseguimos uma melhor performance se fizermos uso de [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) e da sua característica de não armazenar valores duplicados, assim podemos simplesmente verificar se comprimento do `set` é diferente (menor) do que o número de pessoas (`num_p`), se for é porque houveram valores duplicados, e tivemos pelo menos duas pessoas a fazer anos no mesmo dia (`favoraveis += 1`):

```
import random

num_p = int(input("Digite o número de pessoas: "))
num_loops = int(input("Digite o número de repetições: ")) # num de testes
favoraveis = 0
for _ in range(num_loops):
    ani_dates = {random.randint(1, 366) for _ in range(num_p)} # sortear novo set de datas (dias) de aniversario
    if(len(ani_dates) != num_p): # se o comprimento do set for diferente do num de pessoas
        favoraveis += 1

probs_perc = (favoraveis/num_loops)*100
print('Em {} pessoas e {} testes deram-se {} vezes em que pelo menos duas pessoas fazem anos no mesmo dia, percentagem: {}%'.format(num_p, num_loops, favoraveis, probs_perc))
# Em 23 pessoas e 1000 testes deram-se 506 vezes em que pelo menos duas pessoas fazem anos no mesmo dia, percentagem: 50.6%
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/TwinSweetCopyright)

A equação do aumento exponencial da probabilidade pode ser [vista aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxo_do_anivers%C3%A1rio), e eu ao testar essa mesma equação em python também fiz o gráfico.

Não tem haver com a pergunta mas aqui deixo o código para fazer esse gráfico:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def birthday_probs(x):
    p = (1.0/365)**x
    for i in range((366-x),366):
        p *= i
    return 1-p

plt.plot([birthday_probs(i)*100 for i in range(366)])
plt.xlabel("Num de pessoas")
plt.ylabel("Probabilidades de partilha de dia de aniversário")
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=80)
plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que faz any? Não entendi!

Comment: @EdS estou no telemovel, nao vou conseguir explicar direito mas basicamente é `any(condicao for j in...)` e retorna `True` mal a condição se verifique, senão `False`, neste caso se algum dos valores ocorre mais que uma vez nessa lista. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

Answer (score 4):

Este link pode te ajudar:
[Wikipedia: Paradoxo do Aniversário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxo_do_anivers%C3%A1rio)

Basicamente o código de probabilidades é:

```
def birthday(x):
    p = (1.0/365)**x
    for i in range((366-x),366):
        p *= i
    return 1-p
```